# Copy TreeView Node

Tags: .net, treeview, copy

I am trying to copy the selected treeview node to the clip board so I can paste it in notepad. Here is my code but it doesn't work.

```
    TreeNode selNode = (TreeNode)this.treeView1.SelectedNode;
    Clipboard.SetData("TreeNode", selNode);
```

Answer (score 19):

Notepad doesn't know anything about the Winforms TreeNode class.  Use Clipboard.SetText() instead:

```
    private void treeView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C)) {
            if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null) {
                Clipboard.SetText(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
            }
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

XAML:

> ```
> <TreeView>
>   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
>     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
>       <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ItemLoaded"/>
>     </Style >
>   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
> </TreeView>
> ```

C#:

> ```
> protected void ItemLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   if (sender is TreeViewItem)
>   {
>     TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;
>
>     if (item.CommandBindings.Count == 0)
>     {
>       CommandBinding copyCmdBinding = new CommandBinding();
>       copyCmdBinding.Command = ApplicationCommands.Copy;
>       copyCmdBinding.Executed += CopyCmdBinding_Executed;
>       copyCmdBinding.CanExecute += CopyCmdBinding_CanExecute;
>       item.CommandBindings.Add(copyCmdBinding);
>     }
> }
>
> private void CopyCmdBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>   if (sender is TreeViewItem)
>     if ((sender as TreeViewItem).Header is MyClass)
>       Clipboard.SetText(((sender as TreeViewItem).Header as MyClass).MyValue);
> }
>
> private void CopyCmdBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>   e.CanExecute = false;
>   if (sender is TreeViewItem)
>     if ((sender as TreeViewItem).Header is MyClass)
>       e.CanExecute = true;
> }
> ```

Comment: I love this one... it works BEAUTIFULLY for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want other programs to recognise what's on the clipboard, you need to use a recognised data format (e.g. plain text, or bitmap) string parameter, and to format the tree node into that format (e.g. if you choose text, you should pass a 'string' as the clipboard data, perhaps the TreeNode.Text value).  See [System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.aspx) for the different predefined types.