# WinForms TreeView Copy of Text with Ctrl + C Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, copy-paste

I'm currently running into a problem: I have a TreeView and I can modify the text on the node by double-clicking it (but leaving some time in between) like in normal Windows when you want to rename a file.

And now when I am in this name modification section where the text is highlighted and everything ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofwqb.png)) I can't use Ctrl+C to copy the text. I can only use the Copy function of the context menu when you press right click on it which takes considerably more time than Ctrl+C.

Are the shortcuts in this scenario disabled and if so can I enable them?

Also I have already implemented a functionality for Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V when copying/pasting an entire node, so that's not my question. This problem just has to do with copying the text.

I want to do the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191981/copy-paste-treeview-node-label) but I don't quite understand it since I don't know for example what "Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form." means (I'm also not able to open the Designer)

Comment: I don't have much experience with TreeView but maybe you should look into the Properties of the TreeView and if you can't find anything useful there, you might also add an keydown event and check if ctrl + c is pressend and paste the selection into the users clipboard.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: @sLw The thing is that I don't know where I should add this keydown event… Because copying the text should only work when I'm in this situation where only the text is highlighted. Because later on I might want to add functionality to really copy a list item and not just it's name :/

Comment: @MaciejLos Honestly, nothing, becuase I don't know where to start removing this "bug". I don't think writing an event for KeyPressed or KeyDown would work (read my last comment)

Comment: Check this: [Copy / Paste Treeview Node Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191981/copy-paste-treeview-node-label)

Comment: @MaciejLos Unfortunately I don't quite understand the answer. For example what does he mean with "Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form."?

Comment: @MarkusRechberger dropping a control onto the form means dropping the contorl onto the form.. like when you select a button from the toolbox and drag and drop it onto the form

Comment: @sLw It is possible to add something to the form by drag and drop? Pardon me, but I'm working on an already existing form which I didn't code myself (internship… and this is the first task I have problems with because I have to read myself into 100+ files of code :D )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that when pressing Ctrl+C in the edit mode it uses the normal Ctrl+C handler for entire nodes but "fails" there at an if condition which checks if the correct thing (=node) was selected.

I simply added an else to this which then copies the selected value to the clipboard and it works perfectly fine!
I'll probably just have to do the same thing with Ctrl+V in edit mode.

Gosh, I've searched so long for this solution, thanks to Jochen Arndt who provided me help [in this comment section](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1252872/Winforms-treeview-how-can-I-use-ctrlplusc-for-copy)!